# 1-1 relation load with bookshelf

Tags: bookshelf.js

I have 2 tables something likes;

```
Property {id, name, address_id}
Address {id, city, country, add_line_1, ...}
```

I linked Property to Address via address_id.
How can I config Bookshelf model to load Property with associated Address via address_id.
I'm trying  something likes;

```
PROPERTY = bookshelf.Model.extend({
   tableName: 'PROPERTY',

   address: function() {
       return this.hasOne(ADDRESS, 'address_id');
   }
});

ADDRESS = bookshelf.Model.extend({
   tableName: 'ADDRESS',

   property: function() {
       return this.belongsTo(PROPERTY);
   }
});
```

The error: "Unknown ADDRESS.address_id in where clause"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-hasOne) the `hasOne()` expects the foreign key to be ON THE OTHER table. So try changing your models to:

```
PROPERTY = bookshelf.Model.extend({
   tableName: 'PROPERTY',

   address: function() {
       return this.belongsTo(ADDRESS, 'address_id');
   }
});

ADDRESS = bookshelf.Model.extend({
   tableName: 'ADDRESS',

   property: function() {
       return this.hasOne(PROPERTY);
   }
});
```

And query using, by example:

```
PROPERTY.fetchAll({withRelated:'address'}).then((a)=>
  {console.log(a.toJSON())});
```